# What do "Self" and "# Self" mean in the Time Profiler instrument?

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments

The documentation just says it means "the number of time the symbol calls itself", but what does this mean? And what does "# Self" mean?

When I use Instruments, if "# Self" is equal to 100, then "Self" is also 100.0.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the documentation you read must be incorrect.

**Self** in the Time Profiler refers to the amount of time spent in the given function itself, excluding time spent in other methods that it calls.

**Self %** is the same thing but expressed as a percentage of the total running time.

**# Self** is the number of actual profiler samples that hit this function or method. The Time Profiler samples every 1 ms by default, so this number will often be the same as the *Self* value.